# Template Folder Permissions

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl

Scenario:

Our company HR shared folder has the following directory scheme:

Jane_Doe

- 01_Agreements
- 02_Wages
- 03_Discipline

John_Doe

- 01_Agreements
- 02_Wages
- 03_Discipline

With all 100 employees having 15 folders. The folder permissions for each folder should be as follows:

01_Agreements : Full control to HR and Payroll

02_Wages : Full control to HR and Payroll

03_Discipline : Full control to HR (NO Access to Payroll)

Manually adjusting folder permissions like this is an administration nightmare. Ideally, we would split the root folders in to "HR and Payroll Access" folders and "HR Only Access" folders. That is not a possibility unfortunately.

What I am looking for is a way to quickly apply the appropriate permissions to each of the folders in each of the directories.

Is there any way this can be done? I was reviewing a basic script for adjusting the permissions on one folder, and it seems to work, but I can't sort out how to use multiple usernames/folders in this format:

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
Write-host "My directory is $dir"

$Acl = Get-Acl "$dir\01_TestFolder"
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("bray.g", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "$dir\01_TestFolder" $Acl
```

Comment: Why not use GPOs?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. How does a GPO dynamically and automatically assign folder permissions? I understand I could make a group called "HR Access" and assign permissions to the users in that group to the folders, but i still have the issue of needing folders 1,4,5,6, and 7 to only be accessible to a different group of users. Again, these users can go into a group, but I'd have to manually adjust permissions. If there's something I'm missing, I would love to learn how a GPO could solve this issue - seems like the most straight forward place to manage this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up making a batch file that updates folder permissions. Used this and copied for all necessary folders.

```
REM Used to update/add folder permissions to the Shared HR folder. Adjust as necessary
REM - DR 12/11/2017

icacls "01_Agreements" /t /grant USER.1:(OI)(CI)F
icacls "01_Agreements" /t /grant USER.2:(OI)(CI)F
icacls "01_Agreements" /t /grant UsER.3:(OI)(CI)F

REM Remove "REM" from the next line to delete the file after running
REM del "permissions.bat"
```